# Thoughts on "set of all sets"

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've seen a post on this, but the comments said that this isn't valid. Using only ZF theory, what is wrong with my thoughts on this?

So, let $S$ be the set of all sets. We know $|S|<|\mathcal{P} (S)|$, but because $S$ is the set of $\textit{all}$ sets, it means that $\mathcal{P}(S)\subseteq S$, which implies $|\mathcal{P}(S)|\leq |S|$, and this is obviously a contradiction. Aside from this beeing "too simple", why isn't this considered good argumentation?

Comment: Axiomatically, it is easier to prove no universal set exists than it is to prove CCantor's theorem. But it is still technically a valid proof once you have Cantor's theorem.

Comment: Looks fine to me. And it gives you a bonus bit of trivia about set theories with a universal set: Cantor's theorem must somehow fail in them.

Comment: You start by assuming the existence of something (the set of all sets) that can be shown not to exist. You should also be able to prove $$0=1\implies |\mathcal{P}(S)|\leq |S|$$ illustrating that anything follows from a falsehood.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really understand what point you're trying to make? @DanChristensen

Comment: @DanChristensen I also don't see the point of this remark. The main point of the situation is that you can either use the ZF axioms to prove that there is no universal set, or you can use the ZF axioms to prove Cantor's theorem and then notice that a universal set will violate Cantor's theorem. Yes in principle, the latter argument is an instance of explosion, but so is every other proof by contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that if you have a set S, that contains all sets. Then it must also contain itself, set S.

Simplifying this, by conjecturing that there are no other sets. Only set S exists. And S contains all sets. Because S is a set. It must therefore contain itself.

Therefore set S = {S}

Now there is set S that contains S. And set S that is contained.

However, the 'contained' set S does not contain the 'containing' set S. And the 'containing' set S only contains 'contained' set S.

S can never truly contain itself, and therefore it cannot exist as a consistent set with that rule. Because S must contain, and at the same time be contained.

Another way to look at this is, if S contains only all sets that 'do not contain itself', it must then contain itself, because S 'does not contain itself' (yet).

If S then 'does contain itself', it therefore becomes a set that 'does contain itself', and cannot be in a set that only contains sets that 'do not contain itself'.

Then if it is 'not contained by itself', it must then contain itself again. and so on...

Therefore this set cannot be true. It's a fluctuating set is never satisfied. There are no conditions that hold true for set S. Yet there it is.

Comment: This isn't really valid: there are set theories which don't enforce the axiom of foundation, and indeed have well-defined objects like $A=\{ A \}$. Also, you can't just strip out everything except the universal set anyway.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain a bit more, so I'm sure I understand?

I was under the impression that is the rule for a universal set, that has to contain all sets. it would have to contain itself. Does this not create a recurring issue?

Surely A = {A} works fine, unless it must contain all sets. If it contains itself, it can't contain itself? How does that work?

Comment: Why can you not strip all of the other sets out? Can you in theory have not just one set?

Comment: The universal set must contain all sets, so in particular it must contain itself. So it is not well-founded. But there is no "Russell's paradox" *inherent* in non-well-founded sets. It is just that you have to come up with some other resolution to Russell's paradox than the one used by ZF in order to cook up a non-well-founded set theory without Russell's paradox getting in the way. Quine's New Foundations (short name: NF) is one example.

Comment: While you can talk about a set theory where there is just one object $A$ and $A \in A$, you have stripped away so much of the spirit of set theory at that point that you are no longer really talking about the same subject.

Comment: This statement is false.